# SQL query PHP in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upload

I want to iniserer an image in a database and in a file.

The insertion in the folder works but not in the database or I just want to insert the name of the image.

I make a var_dump of the variable where is the query sql (INSERT INTO) and when I copy the answer of the var_dump in mysql the name is registered well ...

I am at the end of idea have you something to share with me? Thank you in advance I continue my research

My php code:

```js
<?
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=resa', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST['formAjoutHebergement']))
{

  $target = "imgheb/images/".basename($_FILES['imageheb']['name']);
  $temp = explode (".", $_FILES["imageheb"]["name"]);
  $nomimg = $_FILES['imageheb']['name'];


  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageheb"]["tmp_name"],$target)){
    $valide = 'Ok';
    $insertimg = "INSERT INTO hebergement(IMAGEHEB) VALUES('$nomimg')";
    var_dump($insertimg);
  }

  else
  {
    $erreur = "Probleme upload image";
  }
}
?>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ajout photo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align="center">

      <h2>Ajout photo</h2>
      </br></br></br>

      <?php

        if(isset($erreur))
        {
          echo '<font color="#FF0000">'.$erreur."</font>";
        }
        if(isset($valide))
        {
          echo '<font color="#008000">'.$valide."</font>";
        }

      ?>

      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <table>
          <tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">
              <label for="imageheb"> image hebergement :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
              <input type="file" id="imageheb" name="imageheb" required/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center">
              </br>
              <input type="submit" name="formAjoutHebergement" value="Ajouter"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my var_dump that works in sql:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj6z8.png)

Comment: Use prepared statements and check that your field is large enough to gold the file (blob?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only created a string. to execute query,

```
$sql = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO `hebergement` (`IMAGEHEB`) VALUES (?)");
$sql->execute(array($nomimg));
```

Comment: Thank you very much tyro the query works :)! Thanks also to you Cemal it was a good idea